# Getting null object reference error on Context.getResource. when using a custom adapter for recycler view

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, adapter

I'm getting this error whenever I launch my cart activity. I made a recycler view of a customer's orders, and ever since I added a button to allow users to delete items from their cart and tried adding this button to the adapter through using new popup(context,holder.buttonViewOption), I get this error :
Here's the full error message

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.rotekapp, PID: 22120
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
> on a null object reference
> at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.(MenuBuilder.java:200)
> at android.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:103)
> at android.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:78)
> at android.widget.PopupMenu.(PopupMenu.java:63)
> at com.example.rotekapp.CartAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CartAdapter.java:69)
> at com.example.rotekapp.CartAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CartAdapter.java:29)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3686)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530) E/AndroidRuntime:     at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3006)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1833)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2122)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Any Help is appreciated!
My Adapter Class:

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.CartViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<CartItemsModel> list;
private SelectListener listener;
private Context mCtx;

public CartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CartItemsModel> list, SelectListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.listener = listener;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cart_items,parent,false);
    return new CartViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CartItemsModel cartItemsModel = list.get(position);
    int tPrice = cartItemsModel.getTotalPrice();
    String tPriceMod = String.valueOf(tPrice);
    holder.TotalQuantity.setText(cartItemsModel.getTotalQuantity());
    holder.TotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(cartItemsModel.getTotalPrice()));
    holder.ProductPrice.setText(cartItemsModel.getProductPrice());
    holder.ProductName.setText(cartItemsModel.getProductName());
    holder.ProductID.setText(cartItemsModel.getProductID());
    holder.CurrentDate.setText(tPriceMod);
    holder.CurrentTime.setText(cartItemsModel.getCurrentTime());
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onItemClicked(list.get(position));
        }
    });
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.buttonViewOption); <-- Error is here
    popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu1:
                    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders");
                    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    String username = getUser(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                    Query productIDQuery = database.child(username).orderByChild("ProductID").equalTo(cartItemsModel.getProductID());
                    productIDQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot productIDsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                productIDsnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Removed from cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case R.id.menu2:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Quantity: " + cartItemsModel.getTotalQuantity(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });




}

private String getUser(String FullUserName) {
    String fullUserName = FullUserName;
    String firstChar = fullUserName.substring(0);
    int firstCharPos = fullUserName.lastIndexOf(firstChar);
    int atsyPos = fullUserName.indexOf("@");
    String realUserName = fullUserName.substring(firstCharPos, atsyPos);
    return realUserName;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView CurrentDate,CurrentTime,ProductID,ProductName,ProductPrice,TotalPrice,TotalQuantity;
    public CardView cardView;
    public TextView buttonViewOption;


    public CartViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        CurrentDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_date);
        CurrentTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_time);
        ProductID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_id);
        ProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_name);
        ProductPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_price);
        TotalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_tot_price);
        TotalQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_qty);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_container);
        buttonViewOption = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
    }
}




}
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error you get comes from MenuBuilder. Apparently, the context you receive in your adapter constructor hasn't been initialized. Are you sure that when you initialize your adapter, you send a correct context?

It is a good practice to name your variables in lower case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Here is the pastebin of the class in which the adapter is initialized - https://pastebin.com/Y6RUkff6